# Kuberenetes HPA showing <unkown>

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, hpa

I want to use HPA on the frontend service, but I get `<unknown>` rather than a number
Commands ran:

1. kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
   `
2. kubectl get deployment metrics-server -n kube-system

```
 NAME             READY  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE
 metrics-server   0/1    1           0          21s
```

3. kubectl describe hpa 
   `No resources found in default namespace`
4. kubectl autoscale deployment udagram-frontend --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=10
   `horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/udagram-frontend autoscaled`
5. kubectl describe hpa

[image]

deployment file

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: udagram-frontend
  labels:
    service: udagram-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: udagram-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: udagram-frontend
        api: external
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: udagram-frontend
          image: oussamabouchikhi/udagram-frontend:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: '64Mi'
              cpu: '250m'
            limits:
              memory: '1024Mi'
              cpu: '500m'
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Github repo: https://github.com/oussamabouchikhi/udagram-microservices

Comment: Your metrics-server deployment availability is 0 in your screen shot. Can you do a `kubectl get pod -l k8s-app=metrics-server -n kube-system` to ensure metrics-server pod is indeed running?

Comment: If it's not running what should I do?

Comment: try to describe deployment for more  info and logs

Comment: I am facing a problem with my Udacity account I cannot lunch my AWS console so I, unfortunately, cannot test that until hopefully the Udacity support team responds me